# Powershell Question Array and Registry Key

Tags: arrays, powershell, registry

I have code:

```
$RegKey = "HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9"

$CurrentParent = $RegKey
$PresentParentFound = $false
$ParentList = @()

While ($PresentParentFound -eq $false) {    
    if (Test-Path $CurrentParent) {   
        $PresentParentFound = $true       
    }
    else {
        $NextParent = Split-Path $CurrentParent -Parent
        $Last = Split-Path $CurrentParent -Leaf
        $ParentList +=$Last
        $CurrentParent = $NextParent
    }
}
```

$ParentList give me array of :
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

So my problem is i dont know how to make from that array, next array that will contain:

```
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6\7
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8
HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
```

How to do that?
Just a small notice that numbers are just example that can be different for another registry key.
I need that to create function to create registry key without worry about parent registry key present.
like :
Create Key -Key "HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9"
When only "HKLM:\OFFLINE_NTUSER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost" is present.

Tried few things im out of ideas.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I got what you need but if you're asking how to reverse the array and join it with a backslash to be able to combine it with its parent path you may use `$ParentList = 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1; [array]::Reverse($ParentList); $ParentList -join '\'`. ‍♂️

Comment: But your approach sounds weird anyway. Shouldn't it work simply to search for a path with a particular pattern in it to determine the correct key?  ‍♂️

Comment: You may explain what you're actually trying to do. The bigger picture in a way. Not the way you think you have to go to achieve what you need. 

Comment: To me it sounds like you just need to use some conditional `if(){}` logic if the parent key exist using `test-path` or something like that. If x existing, create the new registry path from the array item(s).